# How to write Jetty websocket backend environment

Tags: websocket, server, jetty, real-time, embedded-jetty

I am totally new to WebSockets, as well as to launching a server. What I want to do is actually re-create EXACTLY what was done in this tutorial [HERE](https://dzone.com/articles/face-detection-using-html5). I've done everything up until the step of ,,Setup backend environment" where Jetty comes into action.... So far I have one html file,a java script that should open the websocket (but ofc it throws an error as there is no backend for now) and that's all, I am coding in Visual Studio within ASAP.NET Web Core Application on port: https://localhost:44391/.

My question now is where should I switch in order to write the backend? Can that be still Visual Studio or I should switch to Eclipse f.ex. I am totally lost where I should include this WebSocketServer and FaceDetection classes, what should I download, what kind of project to create?

If someone could explain me what I should do step by step now, I would be really thankful, because the author of this and many other tutorials suppose that the people who read it already know what they have to do more or less, and unfortunately, I have no idea. The tutorial doesn't seem to be complicated so maybe someone kind would have a minute to explain me how to do it from the step ,,Setup backend environment" till the end, or at least how to start?

Answer (score 2):

That dzone article is very old and is referencing a long ago EOL (End of Life) version of Jetty.

Please use something up to date.

See any of the following example code repositories:

- https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook
- https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples
- https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples
- https://github.com/jetty-project/websocket-basic-webapp
- https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-websocket-example
- https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-websocketclient-demo